# Как убрать название ошибки?

Tags: yii2

В Yii2 при попадании на страницу ошибки, например, 404, есть текст Not Found (#404).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при любых ошибках оставить только номер, без текста?

в views/error.php 
Html::encode($this->title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Покажу на примере шаблона basic.
В **app\controllers\SiteController** комментируем следующий код

```
    public function actions()
    {
      return [
        //'error' => [
        //    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        //],
      ];
    }
```

и добавляем своё действие в этот же контроллер

```
public function actionMyerror()
{
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception !== null) {
        $statusCode = $exception->statusCode;
        $name = $exception->getName();
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        $this->layout = 'main';
        return $this->render('error', [
            'exception' => $exception,
            'statusCode' => $statusCode,
            'name' => false,
            'message' => $message
        ]);
    }        
}
```

в конфигурационном файле **app\config\web.php** указываем своё действие для обработок ошибок

```
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/myerror',
    ],
```

в файле **app\views\site\error** выводим только код ошибки

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($statusCode) ?></h1>
```

Всё.
p.s. Шаблон basic взял стандартный, сразу после установки.