# Yii2 свой шаблон ошибки

Tags: php, yii2

В общем есть тема basic, шаблонизатор Smarty, в ней у меня страница ошибки - error.tpl, в контроллере я прописал

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            'view' => '@app/themes/basic/error.tpl'
        ],
    ];
}
```

Также я пробовал

```
'@app/views/error.tpl'
'@app/themes/basic/error.php'
'@app/view/error.php'
```

Но yii абсолютно пофиг на это, выводит стандратное

> Not Found (#404) Страница не найдена. The above error occurred while
>   the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Самое интересное что в самом классе https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/ErrorAction.php#L139 нет по сути никакой обработки ошибок, т.е. я должен гадать указан ли правильно путь к файлу или нет, например... Но не будем о грустном. 
Собственно вопрос - как заставить это работать ?

Answer (score 0):

Покажу на примере шаблона `basic`.
В `app\controllers\SiteController` комментируем следующий код

```
    public function actions()
    {
      return [
        //'error' => [
        //    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        //],
      ];
    }
```

и добавляем своё действие в этот же контроллер

```
public function actionMyerror()
{
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception !== null) {
        $statusCode = $exception->statusCode;
        $name = $exception->getName();
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        $this->layout = 'main';
        return $this->render('error', [
            'exception' => $exception,
            'statusCode' => $statusCode,
            'name' => false,
            'message' => $message
        ]);
    }        
}
```

в конфигурационном файле **app\config\web.php** указываем своё действие для обработок ошибок

```
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/myerror',
    ],
```

в файле **app\views\site\error** выводим только код ошибки

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($statusCode) ?></h1>
```

Шаблон `basic` взял стандартный, сразу после установки.

Comment: Все это замечательно, но вопрос то не в этом был. Вопрос в том почему вот это не работает http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-erroraction.html#$view-detail ? А то что вы написали, я мог и так нагуглить :) Без обид. Кстати вот ваш же ответ один в один, зачем копипастите я хз https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/Как-убрать-название-ошибки Самое печальное, что это далеко не первая вещь которая должна(судя по докам), но не работает из коробки в Yii.

Comment: Вот тут у человека вроде как работает https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334026, а у меня нет :(

Comment: Вы, как я понял, хотите подключить свой вид для вывода ошибки. Вот этот код и должен помочь подменить стандартный вид на свой.

Comment: Повторите в теме стандартную структуру файлов. Где по умолчанию располагается error вид, так и у Вас в теме должно быть.

Comment: _хотите подключить свой вид для вывода ошибки_ Вы абсолютно правы. И судя по докам именно свойство $view должно мне помочь, но не работает, вот в чем проблема. Зачем оно нужно тогда, не совсем понятно.

Comment: В коде, что я дал, подключается error представление, подключите через него. Или в теме, повторив стандартный путь в виду error положите свой файл.

Comment: _повторив стандартный путь_ не работает, я это первым делом попытался сделать, но увы не помогло.

Comment: сейчас протестировал у себя, на стандартном basic, всё работает. Проверьте путь к файлу. Про стандартный путь я имею ввиду, что в теме точно такой же сделать 'view' => '@app/themes/basic/views/site/error.tpl' или какой у Вас путь.

Comment: Проверил и на теме. Путь получился такой 'view' => '@app/themes/portfolio/site/test.php', всё работает

Comment: Ну и код в ответе работает, можно подменить вид. Не только вид, но и текст ошибки подменить. Проверил на теме, не на стандартном файле.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю еще раз чего там не так, а то действительно сртранно - у всех работает, а у меня нет O_0

Comment: Если есть желание, то звоните в skype, мой логин slo_nik . А то так можно долго переписываться.